# Construct a random variable under given constraints

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

In preparation for a probability examination, I am working on the following problem.

#### Problem

A box contains three white balls and ten black balls.
Balls are drawn without replacement until all the white balls are drawn.
Let $Y_0$ be the number of draws made.

Construct a random variable $Y: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ and a distribution $P$ over $\Omega$ such that $Y$ and $Y_0$ have the same distribution.

#### My queries

- Most importantly, what is a good thought process for approaching and solving this problem?
- Is it necessary to determine the distribution of $Y_0$ in order to solve this problem?  If so, how can we determine the distribution of $Y_0$?
- What is the purpose of constructing the distribution $P$, as required?

Comment: Yes, we want the distribution of $Y_0$.  We have $Y_0=k$ if we get $2$ white in the first $k-1$ draws and a white on the $k$-th draw.  As to thought process, maybe work with some concrete $k$. As a simple start, find $\Pr(Y_0=3)$. Then find $\Pr(Y_0=4)$.

Comment: I have tried to determine the distribution of $Y_0$, but have not been able to complete my attempt.  I will work on your suggestion, though.

Comment: An answer has been given by Mark Fischler, showing how to find $\Pr(Y_0=6)$. That should serve as a good guide.

Comment: @AndréNicolas This construction can be made *without* determining the distribution of $Y_0$. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought process:  If I want to construct a distribution $P$ such that $Y_0$ and $Y$ have the same distribution, then I will have to know the distribution $Y_0$. So yes, that is necessary.

And one might want that distribution $P$ because you would like to write a program that simulates how many draws were needed, but consumed only one uniform random variate on $(0,1)$.  Or maybe yo want that distribution because somebody will ask for the expected number of draws, or the expected square or $n$-th power of the number of draws.

The distribution will of course have a domain of $[3,13]$ since you can't finish without 3 draws and you muust finish by the time all 13 balls have been drawn.

I will illustrate how to find $P(6)$:

In order for the 6-th draw to be the last white ball, the first 5 draws must consist of precisely two white and three black balls,  and then the next draw, out of 8 balls, must be the remaining white ball.  So
$$
P(6) = \frac{\binom{3}{2}_{\text{white}}\binom{10}{3}_{\text{bloack}} }{\binom{13}{5}} \times \frac18 = \frac{40}{143}\times \frac{1}{8} = \frac{5}{143}
$$
You can probably do the other numbers by following this example.

Comment: The answer is useful.  What do you mean by 'one might want that distribution $P$ because you would like to write a program that simulates how many draws were needed, but consumed only one uniform random variate on $(0,1)$', please?  In particular, I don't understand the meaning of 'one uniform random variate on $(0,1)$'.  Also, I don't see how our constructing a distribution $P$ would enable us to simulate the number of draws needed.

Comment: A uniform variate on $0,1)$ is a random real number $x$ lying between $0$ and $1$ such that the probability of $x$ being in range $(a,b)$ (that is, from $a$ to $b$) for $a$ and $b$ between zero and one is always $|b-a|$. Lots of languages have functions returning uniform randoms.

Comment: Now, if you have the prob density function $P$, you can cumulatively add $P$ (or integrate if it is continuous) to get the cumulative distribution $C(n)$ which maps the domain (here, 3 to 13) to the interval $(0,1)$. And then you can invert the function to get a map $C^{-1}(x)$ from  $(0,1)$ to $n$. Applying that inverse map to the random variate $x$ gives you a variate $n$ which is distributed according to the density $P$; thus its distribution is the same as that for doing the draw-balls experiment.

Comment: I have tried to use the method in your answer to calculate $P[Y_0 = 3].$  However, I am having an issue.  I have detailed this here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1318328/calculating-probability-distribution-under-given-constraints

Comment: Please do not feel obliged to answer, as somebody has given a helpful answer to my question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1318328/calculating-probability-distribution-under-given-constraints#1318335

Comment: Another way for finding $P(k)$. For $k\in\{3,\dots,13\}$  we have $P(k)=\frac{\binom{k-1}2}{\binom{13}{3}}$. This because $2$ of the first $k-1$ balls must be white ($\binom{k-1}2$ possibilities) and of the remaining balls the first must be white ($1$ possibility). There are $\binom{13}3$ possibilities in total.

Comment: I disagree with first paragraph. It is *not* necessary to know the distribution of $Y_0$. It is enough to know how $Y_0$ is achieved. I would rather think this exercise has been given to make the student aware of that.

Comment: @drhab: this was my initial thought.

Answer (score 0):

For $\Omega$ take the set of all subsets of set $\{1,2,\dots,13\}$ that have exactly $3$ elements.

Note that $\binom{13}3$ is the cardinality of $\Omega$.

As $\sigma$-algebra take $\wp(\Omega)$.

As probability measure take $P$ uniform, i.e. $P(\{\omega\})=\binom{13}3^{-1}$ for each $\omega\in\Omega$.

Finally prescribe $Y:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb R$ by $\omega\mapsto\max\omega$.

Then $Y$ and $Y_0$ have the same distribution.

Note that this construction does not ask you to determine the distribution of $Y_0$. The elements of $\Omega$ are sets like e.g. $\omega_0=\{2,4,7\}$. This example stands for the event that a white ball was drawn at the draws $2$, $4$ and $7$. Here $Y(\omega)=\max\omega=7$, equalizing the number of draws needed to pick out all white balls.

Comment: I am not familiar with the terms '$\sigma$-algebra' and 'probability measure'.

Comment: They are essential ingredients of what is called a [probability space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space). It is kind of weird that you are not familiar with them while at the same time you are following a course in probability.

Comment: I see.  I can look at the definitions.