# Calculating probability distribution under given constraints

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

I recently asked a question about the construction of a random variable under given constraints (see: [Construct a random variable under given constraints](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1317186/construct-a-random-variable-under-given-constraints/1317220?noredirect=1#comment2676567_1317220)).

The only answer to my question suggested a method of calculating the probability distribution, giving an example for the case $P[Y_0 = 6]$.
I used this example, as well as another method, to find $P[Y_0 = 3]$; however, I am not sure which approach is correct.

#### First attempt

I initially tried to find $P[Y_0 = 3]$ thus.

The total number of ways of choosing $3$ balls from $13$ is $13 \choose 3$.
There are $3!$ ways of choosing three white balls on the first three draws.
So, I think that

$$P[Y_0 = 3] = \frac{3!}{13 \choose 3} = \frac{3}{143}.$$

#### Second attempt

However, when I use the method suggested in the answer in the link above, I obtain the following.

The first two draws must be two white balls and the third one must be, out of $11$ balls, the remaining white ball.
Hence

$$P[Y_0 = 3] = \frac{3 \choose 2}{13 \choose 2} \times \frac{1}{11} = \frac{6}{13 \cdot 12 \cdot 11} = \frac{1}{286}.$$

Which of the attempts is incorrect and why, please?

NB: I think that the root of this issue may be a lack of understanding as to whether or not the order in which the balls are chosen matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first attempt is incorrect in the sense that you use the wrong numerator. Only $1$ (not $3!$) of the $\binom{13}3$ possibilities gives the three white balls so the correct answer is: $$\frac1{\binom{13}3}=\frac1{286}$$

Another reasoning, leading to this outcome.

Event $Y_0=3$ can be verbalized as: the first ball drawn must be white, then the second again must be white and finally the third must be white as well. The probability that the first ball is white is $\frac3{13}$. Assuming that this has occurred then the probability that the second is again white is $\frac2{12}$. Finally assuming that also this has occurred the probability that the third is white is $\frac1{11}$. That gives you:$$P(Y_0=3)=\frac3{13}\times\frac2{12}\times\frac1{11}=\frac{3!}{13\times12\times11}=\frac1{286}$$

Here $3!$ serves as numerator.

Comment: So, could I still have arrived at the correct solution by keeping the numerator, in the first attempt, as $3!$?

Comment: That is, is there a way to obtain the correct solution by considering the possible orderings (permutations) of the draws, instead of simply considering the combinations?

Comment: Ah - your edits have answered both of my questions!

Comment: Glad to help, so you are welcome.